# Rendering in backbone.js with underscore templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I try to render a list of item using underscore's template. But it displays nothing.

I tried to create 2 views, one is a task and one is a task list, but I'm stuck at using template.

- What does `.render()` do?
- if I use template, do I still need to render?

I thought the data will map the template variable when you do `this.$el.html(template_var)`?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/template" id="task_list">
            <li><%=title%></li>
            <li><%=priority%></li>
        </script>

        </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        (function(){

        window.App = {
            Models:{},
            Collections:{},
            Views:{}
        };

        window.template = function(id){
            return _.template( $('#' + id).html() );
        }
        

        App.Models.Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
                title: 'default',
                priority: 1
        });

        App.Collections.Task = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: App.Models.Task
        });

        App.Views.Task = Backbone.View.extend({
            template: template('task_list'),
            render(){
                var template = this.template( this.model.toJSON() );
                console.log(template)
                this.$el.html(template);
                return this;
            }
        })

        App.Views.Tasks = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: 'ul',
            render: function(){
                this.collection.each( this.addOne, this);
                return this;
            },
            addOne: function(task){
                var taskView = new App.Views.Task({ model: task})
                taskView.render();
                this.$el.append(taskView.render().el);
            }
        })

        var tasks = new App.Collections.Task([
            {
                    title: 'Go to store',
                    priority: 4
                },
                {
                    title: 'Eat',
                    priority: 3
                },
                {
                    title: 'Sleep',
                    priority: 4
                }
        ])

        var tasksView = new App.Views.Tasks({collection: tasks})
        $('body').html(tasksView.el)

        })()

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were really close, but there were small problems.

Backbone does a lot of things, but one thing it doesn't do for you is the rendering logic, which is left completely up to the developer. So, you need:

- a template to separate the HTML from the the JS logic.
- a `render` function which does the rendering using your favorite technique, jQuery in our case.

---

A Backbone view always has a [root DOM element (`el`)](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) even if it was not rendered yet, which is a `div` by default if `tagName` isn't specified.

So your task view looked something like this when rendered:

```
<div>
    <li>Go to store</li>
    <li>4</li>
</div>
```

I changed the template a little to work.

---

I moved the CSS back to the HEAD section. This is a standard, but was not really one of the problem.

---

Default attributes in a model should be specified in the [`defaults` property](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults).

---

Defining function with the [shorthand syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) like the following is only available in ES6 (ECMAScript 2015).

```
render(){
```

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), a shorter syntax for method definitions on objects initializers is introduced. It is a shorthand for a function assigned to the method's name.

And to make it [compatible with most browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#Browser_compatibility), you should use:

```
render: function() {
```

---

You also forgot to call render on the list view.

```
$('body').html(tasksView.el)
```

Should be:

```
$('body').html(tasksView.render().el);
```

---

Since your code is inside an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), you don't need to make your app and functions global with the `window`, a local `var` is enough and is a better coding practice.

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- CSS should be in the head -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js"></script>

    <script type="text/template" id="task_list">
        <%=title%> (<%=priority%>)
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {

            var App = {
                Models: {},
                Collections: {},
                Views: {}
            };

            function template(id) {
                return _.template($('#' + id).html());
            }


            App.Models.Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
                defaults: {
                    title: 'default',
                    priority: 1
                }
            });

            App.Collections.Task = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: App.Models.Task
            });

            App.Views.Task = Backbone.View.extend({
                template: template('task_list'),
                tagName: 'li',
                render: function() {
                    var template = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
                    console.log(template)
                    this.$el.html(template);
                    return this;
                }
            });

            App.Views.Tasks = Backbone.View.extend({
                tagName: 'ul',
                render: function() {
                    this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
                    return this;
                },
                addOne: function(task) {
                    var taskView = new App.Views.Task({
                        model: task
                    })
                    this.$el.append(taskView.render().el);
                }
            });

            var tasks = new App.Collections.Task([{
                title: 'Go to store',
                priority: 4
            }, {
                title: 'Eat',
                priority: 3
            }, {
                title: 'Sleep',
                priority: 4
            }]);

            var tasksView = new App.Views.Tasks({
                collection: tasks
            });
            $('body').html(tasksView.render().el);

        })()
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `$('body').html(tasksView.render().el);` Why I still need to call render again here? Ins't I already use `return this` at the end of my render method?

Comment: @Sandy `return this` is just for chaining calls. You need to call that line because `render` wouldn't be called anywhere otherwise.

Comment: strange I've seen something like without render like `$('body').html(tasksView.el);` but I forgot where

Comment: @Sandy Yeah, it's totally possible to use `$('body').html(tasksView.el);` like that, we just need to call `tasksView.render();` before, or after, or on the same line.